# Deserialize JSON containing an anonymous function using .net

Tags: json, serialization, anonymous-function

I am getting a .net run-time error when attempting to desrialize a JSON string that contains an anonymous function:

Invalid JSON primitive: function.

JSON string itself looks like this:

{
  Action: "fadeIn",
  Callback: function(){doSomething();}
}

This makes me wonder if it is allowed to have anonymous functions in JSON strings that are to be serialized in .net. More specfically I can only use the .net frameworks's own JavaScriptSerializer class for deserialization. Can anyone confirm this, or have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is a **data representation protocol**, and as such it can only be used to represent data, not behavior (which is what functions are). As your deserializer told you, what you have is not valid JSON (it's a valid *JavaScript object*, though, which causes some confusion). Check the [JSON spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627) for more details on this format.

So to your question - no, you cannot deserialize JSON containing function, because it's not JSON in the first place.